# How to know if the markdown preview is focused using contributes commands - VSCode Extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking for something similar to `"when": "markdownPreviewFocus"` which is mentioned in [vscode package.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/0d584a908611a819db0167c26028419cd08830d6/extensions/markdown-language-features/package.json#L91). unfortunately, when I try it shows that `markdownPreviewFocus` is not supported in `when` condition.

```json
"editor/title": [
    {
        "command": "extension.my_command",
        "when": "markdownPreviewFocus==false",
        "group": "navigation"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"when": "!markdownPreviewFocus"
```

Comment: This works for me in VS Code insiders (1.24). Where is the error coming from?

Comment: that's strange.. today it's working fine. must've been some typo in my code.